# What kind of matrix is Matrix $Z_{k}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If we multiply matrix $Z_{k}$ with matrix $A=[a_{i,j}]$ we get matrix $A'=[a'_{i,j}]$ for which is states:

$a'_{i,j}$= 0, if i=k

$a'_{i,j}$ = $a_{i,j}$, otherwise.

My question is, what does the subscript k in $Z_{k}$ represent ?

Matrix in form k x k… Or something else.

I guess matrix $Z_{k}$ has form $Z_{i,i}$  if k subscript represents square matrix, because matrix A' we get, has the same form as A. But if that's the case, I don't understand why wouldn't it be denoted that way $Z_{i}$ where i represent number of rows of matrix A.

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: Could you please use mathjax? I am seeing some really strange symbols, which are definitely not intended...

Comment: @PrudiiArca Yes sir, sorry about that.

Comment: @Saad Edited. I hope it is better now.

Comment: Thank you very much :) I would have liked to help but could not read anything. Thanks for editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disagree with that answer.  While "$Z_k$" is a standard notation for a k by k matrix, here we are given a different definition.  For example, suppose $A= \begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$.  Then $Z_1$ is the matrix, $Z_1= \begin{bmatrix}p & q \\ r & s \end{bmatrix}$ such that $\begin{bmatrix}p & q \\ r & s \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}$.

Since $\begin{bmatrix}p & q \\ r & s \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}pa+ qc & pb+ qd \\ ra+ sc & pc+ qd\end{bmatrix}$ we must have pa+ qc= 0, pb+ qd= 0, ra+ sc= c, and pc+ qd= d.  Solve those four equations for p, q, r, and s.

For $Z_2$ do the same except that we must have $\begin{bmatrix}p & q \\ r & s \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: That's it ! I solved the rest, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In linear algebra generally subscript number of a matrix denotes the size of square matrix as in your condition k×k square matrix $Z_{k \times k}$ or $Z_{k}$ denoted like this.
As you can guess only one number is enough to define the size of the square matrix so $Z_{k}$ notation is used more frequently.
Also for the other types, $Z_{n \times k}$ is used.

Comment: Thank you, I suspected that's the case, what confused me why it wouldn't be denoted as $Z_{i}$ because we see matrix A' has the same form as A, meaning Z matrix has to have i rows too.

Comment: @Damon33_Flown you're welcome but actually i and j are dummy variable and they don't represent the boundaries of the size of the matrix directly but $Z_{k}$ does so k is used instead of i.

Comment: Oh, got it, thank you once again.